# How to use division with window function and Case when statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, case-when

it work with sum() but not sum()/sum()

work with sum():

```
select *, 
case when time_of_day_viewers_time_zone >= '06:00:00 -
06:59:59' and time_of_day_viewers_time_zone <= '10:00:00 - 10:59:59'
then sum(amount_spent_usd) over () else null end as cpm 
from t1
```

not work with sum()/sum():

```
select *,
case when time_of_day_viewers_time_zone >= '06:00:00 - 06:59:59'
and time_of_day_viewers_time_zone <= '10:00:00 - 10:59:59'
then sum(amount_spent_usd)/sum(impressions)*1000 
over () else null end as cpm
from t1
```

edit1: even i use sum(amount_spent_usd)/nullif(sum(impressions),0)*1000 it still said 'syntax error at or near "over" '

edit2:

```
sum(amount_spent_usd) over () / (sum(impressions) over () * 1000)
```

if i use this query, it sums all 24 hour , it means that the case when statement is not applied. How to fix this?

edit4:
finally i use this query although it long..

```
 (sum(case when time_of_day_viewers_time_zone >= '06:00:00 - 06:59:59'
and time_of_day_viewers_time_zone <= '10:00:00 - 10:59:59'
then amount_spent_usd else null end) over () /sum(case when time_of_day_viewers_time_zone >= '06:00:00 - 06:59:59'
and time_of_day_viewers_time_zone <= '10:00:00 - 10:59:59'
then impressions else null end) over ())*1000 as new
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Specify not work. wild guess: division by zero?

Comment: @Turo even i use sum(amount_spent_usd)/nullif(sum(impressions),0)*1000  it still said 'syntax error at or near "over" '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `over()` for two window functions, you need to provide the windowing clause for each function separately. And the multiplication needs to be done on the whole expression:

```
sum(amount_spent_usd) over () / (sum(impressions) over () * 1000)
```

Comment: funny how i figure it out after i ask this. "cry smile" thank you.

Comment: hello, i found a big problem, if i use this query, it sums all 24hour , it means that the case when statement is not applied

Comment: @HaoHao . . . This answers the question that you asked here -- which is about a syntax error.  If you have a more elaborate question, ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation of what you are trying to do.